# Umbraco 8 - Import Members and link to related content

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco8

I have an import function in my v8 app where users can import members.

The members have several extended properties, including  the organisation they belong to, the organisations are documents themselves and contain all info on that organisation.

Adding a member in the back office, the organisation is selected when the user clicks the 'Add' button.

[image]

Each member contains the organisation name which I can run an Examine query and find the organisation document (and therefore it's Id), how can I add (or link) it to the member during an inport?

Here is the code so far showing the Examine query and the line where I would set the imported member organisation.  On checking, the member is added, but nothing appears where organisation should be added.

```
var searcher = index.GetSearcher();
                var results = searcher.CreateQuery("content").NodeTypeAlias("organisation").And().Field("clientName", member.OrganisationName).Execute();
                var _id = "";
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    _id = result.Id;
                }
                customMember.SetValue("organisation", _id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that `foreach`, but you're using a wrong format for your value.

`ContentPicker` FieldType uses a comma-separated list of `Udi`'s, not `GUID`'s.

So for example a value is stored as:
`umb://document/0e906531af9c4244a6be542bc7dd4774,umb://document/6d00ed735cbf47e1a88a0647372b4372`

To set a value programatically you should use `Udi` classes, for example:

```
var udi = Udi.Create(Constants.UdiEntityType.Document, node.Key);
customMember.SetValue("organisation", locaUdi.ToString());
```